# jVectorMap on hover do click

Tags: jvectormap

I've set up a jVectorMap and I want to change the behaviour of it slightly so that when a user hovers over a marker, the same behaviour as the default 'click' behaviour will happen.

Do any of you know how I could go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just like the onMarkerClick event, there is also an onMarkerOver event as listed in the documentation. http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/

onMarkerOver - Will be called on marker mouse over event.

onMarkerClick - Will be called on marker click event.

So any functions you had currently executing on a click can be moved to the onRegionOver event and you should get the functionality you are looking for.